# How to add a loading spinner to existing jQuery AJAX click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to have a click function fade out content, fade in loading spinner, fade out loading spinner, then fade in new content, also have my Url change with history.pushstate. **Everything above is achieved *except* showing my Spinner**.

```
jQuery('.jax a, .page-navigation a').live('click', function(event) {
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'),
            title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        jQuery('#main-content').fadeOut('4000', function(){
        jQuery('#main-content').load(url+' #main-content', function(){
        jQuery('#main-content').fadeIn('4000');
        document.title = title;
        history.pushState({url:url,title:title}, title, url );
    });
});
        return false;
});
```

My spinner **.spinner** is set to **display:none**, and I just can't get it to work with my current code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well... where exactly in this code is your spinner being manipulated? You are not selecting '.spinner' anywhere...

Comment: This posted code is without the spinner. I'd like to have someone show me where/how to implement it.

Comment: I see. Check if my answer satisfies your needs. It doesn't fade in the spinner, only shows it and hides it instead, which I think is more natural. If you really prefer it to fade in and out, let me know and I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if the code below works:

```
jQuery('.jax a, .page-navigation a').live('click', function(event) {
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'),
    title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
    jQuery('#main-content').fadeOut('4000', function(){
        // Loading will start, show spinner
        jQuery('.spinner').show();
        jQuery('#main-content').load(url+' #main-content', function(){
            // Loading is over, hide spinner
            jQuery('.spinner').hide();
            jQuery('#main-content').fadeIn('4000');
            document.title = title;
            history.pushState({url:url,title:title}, title, url );
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I had tried this as well but my problem with the code was within the HTML. My <div class="spinner"></div> was placed within the div that was being loaded thus not showing. When I placed my spinner outside of that div, it began to show. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce your hide / show code by adding:

```
$(document).bind({
   ajaxStart: function(){
         $("#main-content").hide();
         $(".spinner").show(); 
   },
   ajaxStop: function(){
         $("#main-content").show();
         $(".spinner").hide();
   }
});
```